# How can I update an hstore[] field?

Tags: postgresql, array, hstore

I have table `products`, in which there is an hstore array field `countries_of_origin`.

So a product that is assembled from multiple products might have multiple countries of origin:

```
[
  { "country" => "USA" },
  { "country" => "MEX" }
]
```

My only issue is, I have no idea whatsoever on how to write a SQL `update`. Our developers interact with the table via an ORM. But I sometimes have to do a mass update for expediency's sake, and I don't know to do it!

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [examples](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html) for `hstore` in the PostgreSQL documentation.

`UPDATE tab SET h = h || ARRAY['b => 2'::hstore,'c => 3'::hstore];`

Comment: That looks like it will just work for ```hstore```, not ```hstore[]```. But by trying a combination of a couple of things on that page I came up with:

    ```update products set brands = ARRAY['country=>USA'::hstore,'country=>RUS'::hstore] where id = 2;```

Comment: You're quite right. I've updated the example for hstore[] instead of hstore. My apologies.